# Query - Date as a column header

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I had this query that returns a result like this:

**Query**

```
select 
   d.veiculo, d.data_op, d.total_custo_op
from 
   fato_distribuicao d
left join dim_frota f 
   on d.veiculo = f.placa
left join schema_staging.staging_rotas_percorridas p 
   on p.placa = d.veiculo and p.data_operacao = d.data_op
where 
   d.uneg_dist = 'RJA'
   and d.data_op between '2016-07-18' and '2016-07-23'
   and f.tipo1 = 'AGREGADO'
group by d.veiculo, d.data_op, d.total_custo_op, p.setor
order by d.veiculo, d.data_op;
```

**Result**

```
veiculo data_op     total_custo_op

BTB7632 2016-07-19  219
BTB7632 2016-07-21  150
BTB7632 2016-07-22  176
DMI1082 2016-07-18  150
DMI1082 2016-07-19  168
DMI1082 2016-07-20  136
DMI1082 2016-07-21  163
DMI1082 2016-07-22  184
EJC1713 2016-07-18  205
EJC1713 2016-07-19  185
EJC1713 2016-07-20  190
EJC1713 2016-07-21  200
EJC1713 2016-07-22  179
GZG1647 2016-07-18  248
GZG1647 2016-07-20  279
GZG1647 2016-07-21  276
GZG1647 2016-07-22  314
GZG1647 2016-07-23  188
```

But I would need to transform this result and present this query with the range of dates as a column header and `total_custo_op` as data, like this:

**Expected**

```
veiculo 2016-07-18  2016-07-19  2016-07-20  2016-07-21  2016-07-22  2016-07-23
BTB7632 null        219         null        150         176         null
DMI1082 150         168         136         163         184         null
EJC1713 205         185         190         200         179         null
GZG1647 248         null        279         276         314         188
```

I did a pivot query with **ARRAY_AGG** but I just can separate the dates as data. And I can't use the tablefunc module.

Comment: what you want is called Pivot i think.

Comment: Google "PIVOT Postgres" ... are the number of date columns fixed?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the numbers of date can be fixed, it usually will be 5 or 6 (work days), but I can fix to 7 days. I googled this but I didn't have success.

Comment: You should look at the docs for the [tablefunc contrib module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html). It includes functions like `crosstab`, which should be able to do what you want.

Comment: @jmelesky I know it's possible with tablefunc, but it's the contrib module isn't installed in my db, and I don't have permission to intall... So I'd like another way to do this, if it's possible...

Comment: You could write your own functions to do a similar thing to `crosstab`. If you can't make custom functions, then I don't think this is possible within the database.

Comment: @jmelesky: Not preferable, but still *possible*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fix base query

First off, your query has problems. You have a `LEFT JOIN`, followed by a `WHERE` condition, that's nonsense.

Move the condition `f.tipo1 = 'AGREGADO'` to the join clause if you actually want a `LEFT JOIN`. But that wouldn't make sense in your query. Rather, use a plain `JOIN`.

And it's nonsense to add `p.setor` to `GROUP BY` while you don't show it in the result. Actually, `GROUP BY` does not make any sense in your query at all, since you do not aggregate anything. You may be looking for `DISTINCT` or `DISTINCT ON`?

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

So:

```
SELECT d.veiculo, d.data_op, d.total_custo_op
FROM   fato_distribuicao d
JOIN   dim_frota         f ON f.placa = d.veiculo
LEFT   JOIN schema_staging.staging_rotas_percorridas p ON p.placa = d.veiculo
                                                      AND p.data_operacao = d.data_op
WHERE  d.uneg_dist = 'RJA'
AND    d.data_op BETWEEN '2016-07-18' AND '2016-07-23'
AND    f.tipo1 = 'AGREGADO'
-- GROUP  BY d.veiculo, d.data_op, d.total_custo_op  -- , p.setor  -- ??
ORDER  BY d.veiculo, d.data_op;
```

#### Pivot solution

To pivot **without `crosstab()`**, you can use aggregates on `CASE` statements like this:

```
SELECT veiculo
     , min(CASE WHEN data_op = '2016-07-18' THEN total_custo_op END) AS "2016-07-18"
     , min(CASE WHEN data_op = '2016-07-19' THEN total_custo_op END) AS "2016-07-19"
     , -- etc.
FROM  (
  <query from above>
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1;
```

`crosstab()` would be faster and more elegant, though:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: Thanks man. So, I add `p.setor` to `GROUP BY` was really wrong, because I shortened the query but forgot this part. The condition `f.tipo1 = 'AGREGADO'` I moved in the `JOIN` clause. I didn't try to use this clause. But I don't know how to fix the `LEFT JOIN` followed by a `WHERE` clause, because it's necessary to use the both clause. Anyway thank you so much to help me.